# Method (...)__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getOptionArray() on null

Tags: php, magento2

I receive an error when going in backend Catalog->Categories:

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getOptionArray() on
>   null in
>   /home/hubert09/domains/domadeco.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

I found it after upgrade Magento from 2.2.0-rc to 2.2.5

thanks to magento profiler i found the problem is in:
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/edit/assign_products.phtml

```
$block->getGridHtml();
```

that line generate problems

**=======SOLVED=========**

problem caused by 3th part module Oneleek_DraggableProducts. On 2.2.5 it doesnt work. Turn off that module solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**IF You migrated M1 to M2 then you are facing something below error during cmd execution The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.**

please

> don't change in vendor

module-store files :

> /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php or
>
> /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php

just simply apply below steps:

I just recently came across this same situation after migrating from Magento 1.9.3.8 to 2.3.0 and hope my answer can be of assistance. The problem came from deleting multiple stores 96 of them to be exact. I tried all the other answers here but was still getting the same error.

The fix for me was removing the old store data from inside of the "core_config_data". The problem is that when the Magento is loading the run time configuration data it is finding the old stores and trying to resolve them. Before cleaning the data from the database I HIGHLY recommend you run the SELECT query below to make sure you delete the correct stores.

> SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE scope = 'stores';

WARNING: MAKE SURE TO BACKUP YOUR DATABASE BEFORE RUNNING THIS!

> DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE scope_id != 1 AND scope = 'stores';

Now execute all magento commands you can see the "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again" fixed by query

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception in
>   C:\wamp64\www\mage2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

Now check your admin above fatal error also solved blahhh... blahh...

> (Note fatal error_Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString()
>   depedent store module so don't change module-store vendor otherwise
>   admin side grid/list catalog you can'not see proper data)